# SSL Public Key Certificates

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I am working on a Java Desktop Client Application, where i have to store .p12 **Public** certificates with alias names and and when user selects particular alias, it should open IE Browser with predefined link and respective certificate selected.

I have researched about Java Keystore and Keytool Commands.

My questions are:

1) Is it possible to save .p12 extension certificates to java keystore.

2) If above point (1) is valid, is it possible to open the IE browser with respective certificate selected.

Please Help Guys

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is it possible to save .p12 extension certificates to java
>   keystore.

There is no such thing. P12 is a keystore type and not a certificate.

> 2) If above point (1) is valid, is it possible to open the IE browser
>   with respective certificate selected.

It is not valid, but you can configure IE to use your own keystore. Just import it